# Is there any way to change Outlook VBA Read-Only objects via code? (Specifically CurrentUser.Address and .Name)

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am attempting to write some code that will allow the user to change the selected accounts current user's name and address. This is to allow the user (who owns their own domain) to send an email from any email address within that domain, and also any name within the domain.

The reason for this is because the user owns the domain and whichs to operate in separate roles, such as a different address for sales, operations, support, ect. There are too many different addresses to simply make a separate "account" object for each role.

I tried using .sendonbehalfof, but that does sends an email exactly as you would expect, with a sent from name of:

sales@myDomain.com sent on behalf of .

When I use

```
Set Application.Session.Accounts.Item(1).CurrentUser.Name = "WhhateverIwant"
```

It blows up with an error saying "Compile Error: Expected: Expression"

Help! How can I change the CurrentUser name and email address via VBA code?

Answer (score 1):

Set the MailItem.SendUsingAccout property to one of the Account objects from the Application.Session.Accounts collection.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, there is a whole bunch of potential emails addresses that could be used. The account will be for a domain, but then they could use any email address within that domain. Does that make sense?

Comment: In case of Exchange, set the MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName property to the name of the GAL user on whose behalf the current user can send.